# Restricting hasMany relationship where child.field != parent.field without joins

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm looking for a way to qualify a `hasMany` relationship to exclude/include children where the value a specific child field does/not match that of a specific parent field **without using joins**.

The issue with joins is that the `->select()` filters out many descendant relationships (unless they are each added to the join, which is too much to manage). The descendant relationships for example would be `order_item.options` which is a `belongsToMany` of OrderItem.

Case in point:

```
class Order extends Model
{

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class, 'order_id', 'id');
    }

    public function items_removed_by_store()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class, 'order_id', 'id')
            //->join('order', 'order_item.order_id', 'order.id')
            //->where('order_item.deleted_by', '!=', 'order.customer_id')
            //->select('order_item.*', 'order.customer_id')
            ->onlyTrashed();
    }

    public function items_removed_by_customer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class, 'order_id', 'id')
            //->join('order', 'order_item.order_id', 'order.id')
            //->where('order_item.deleted_by', '=', 'order.customer_id')
            //->select('order_item.*', 'order.customer_id')
            ->onlyTrashed();
    }

}
```

and I'm looking to query it like:

```
Location::has('orders.items_removed_by_customer')->get()
```

Get me locations where customers have removed items from their orders.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are currently joining the relationship on its parent. Note you already have the parent data

Maybe try something like this

```
class Order extends Model
{

    public function items()
    {
        // Note: it is not required to pass 'order_id', 'id' to this method as thats the default value
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }

    public function items_removed_by_store()
    {
        return $this->items()
            ->where('order_items.deleted_by', '!=', $this->customer_id)
            ->onlyTrashed();
    }

    public function items_removed_by_customer()
    {
        return $this->items()
            ->where('order_item.deleted_by', '=', $this->customer_id)
            ->onlyTrashed();
    }

}
```

Comment: ```$this->anything``` does not work on collections. So when you do ```$location->orders->load('items_removed_by_customer')``` it is ignored and will return the wrong results.

Comment: You can try ```$location->orders->each->load('items_removed_by_customer')``` but that's an N+1 issue

Comment: You can use ```->whereHas()``` on the query and maybe a ```HasManyThrough``` relationship on `Location`

Comment: I'm loading hundreds of locations. This would induce hundreds of DB calls.

Comment: Maybe you need a HasManyThrough or you look into this package https://github.com/mpyw/eloquent-has-by-join

Comment: so how would the `items_removed_by_customer` relationship query declared in the `Order` class look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248114/discussion-between-monove-and-rawslugs).